# Google Play In-App Purchase Error: "Couldn't complete your purchase"

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I'm adding in-app purchases to my Android application. I've completed all the steps to fetch the products, display them to the user, and start the purchase flow. Now, I'm trying to test it. To do that, I added a test account to the license testers in the Google Play Console.

When I start the purchase flow, I get this UI:

[image: Purchase flow]

But when I click "1-tap buy," I get the following error:

[image: Couldn't complete your purchase. Check that you have the correct country selected in your Play account.]

Here are some things I've already tried:

- I checked that I have the correct country selected in my Play account:

[image: Checked the country]

- I made sure that the address in the payment profile of the test account has the correct country.
- I made sure that the app is published on the Production, Open testing, and Internal testing channels.
- I made sure that the test account is enrolled in the Internal and Closed test tracks.
- I tried testing on an emulator and a physical device.
- I cleared the app data and the cache data of the Google Play Store on my device.
- I installed and used a VPN to test the purchase from different countries.

Any idea what could be causing this issue? Also, if you have any suggestions about stuff I should try, please let me know even if you're not sure whether they will actually work.

Comment: facing the same error, have u found a solution ?

Comment: No, Still facing the same issue.

Comment: It is not development issue, because this issue is facing me in all apps, and in in app purchases in general. This is a general issue not app specific

Comment: Same issue, did anyone fix this.

Comment: I have contacted Google support like a month ago and they told me that they're looking into it and need some time. I checked up on them a few times since, and I was told that they're still investigating. So I'm still waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Google updated their policies few months ago. They prevent commonly-known VPNS from making a payment with the following `couldn't complete your purchase. check that you have the correct country`.

The only known way to bypass this as of now is to use residential vpns, or be in the actual country.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm facing the same issue even without any VPN installed. I'm already in the country and I don't usually install or use VPNs, I just installed and tried to use a VPN because I was facing this issue in the first place.

Comment: Yes unfortunately even being the Country that is the same with GPlay country and paying with the card, that was issued in the said country results in error in some applications.

Comment: Hi there, the reason I am assuming you are not fro mTurkey in the first place is because you are dodging the most simplest solution of contacting Google. When you contact google customer support, they will have you fill a form that will be processed by their investigation team, who will then check if you are indeed someone from said country. Once this is approved, only then you will be able to use payment in Turkish Lira. The fact that I don't see this surface as one of your troubleshoot steps explained a lot to me at the very least, which is why I proposed the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and have tried everything you listed, but nothing worked. My solution: Go to device/phone Settings > Network & Internet > Advanced > Turn **off** the VPN and Private DNS > Restart the device/phone.

Comment: I was already testing without any VPN installed on the device and I was facing the same issue.